# How would I combine Pandas DataFrames with slightly different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a few DataFrames. One of them has some added columns, and some removed columns. The first column of both is a date column, and df2 picks up where the df1 left off, chronologically.

```
df1:
day     alice  bob
8/11    0      0
8/25    2      5
9/1     2      0

df2:
day     alice  charlie
9/12    1      1
9/25    2      3
9/1     2      1
```

I would like to combine them, to get one DataFrame with all dates and all columns present.

```
df3: 
day     alice  bob  charlie
8/11    0      0      0 
8/25    2      5      0 
9/1     2      0      0
9/12    1      0      1
9/25    2      0      3
9/1     2      0      1
```

When I combine my actual 2 DataFrames with pd.concat *or* pd append, i get the following error:

```
AssertionError: Number of manager items must equal union of block items
# manager items: 65, # tot_items: 66
```

Not sure what the issue could be. In the meantime, thanks and you're awesome.  I can provide to you a more fleshed out example if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is correct:

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2]).fillna(0)
```

But here is error:

> AssertionError: Number of manager items must equal union of block items # manager items: 65, # tot_items: 66

It means there are duplicated columns names, you can verify it:

```
print (df1.loc[:, df1.columns.duplicated(keep=False)])
print (df2.loc[:, df2.columns.duplicated(keep=False)])
```

If same values in columns is possible remove duplicated by:

```
df1 = df1.loc[:, ~df1.columns.duplicated()]
df2 = df2.loc[:, ~df2.columns.duplicated()]
df = pd.concat([df1,df2]).fillna(0)
```

Comment: thanks! I used what you gave me to fix it. Peace be upon you friend!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1.set_index("day"), df2.set_index("day")]).fillna(value=0).reset_index()
```

Comment: Im getting back:   raise KeyError(f"None of {missing} are in the columns")
KeyError: "None of ['day'] are in the columns"

Answer (score 0):

```
df1['charlie']=0
df2['bob']=0
df=pd.concat([df1,df2]).reset_index().drop(['index'],axis=1)
```

Explanation: You can add the columns missing in the respective data frames. Now, if you concat(), no error will be raised.

Comment: still getting: AssertionError: Number of manager items must equal union of block items
# manager items: 65, # tot_items: 66

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a DataFrame with all dates and columns present, you can use [DataFrame.combine_first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html).

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create df1
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'day': ['8/11', '8/25', '9/1'],
    'alice': [0, 2, 2],
    'bob': [0, 5, 0]
}).set_index('day')

# Create df2
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'day': ['9/12', '9/25', '9/1'],
    'alice': [1, 2, 2],
    'charlie': [1, 3, 1]
}).set_index('day')

# Do combine_first
df = df2.combine_first(df1).fillna(0)
```

### Initial dataframes

df1

```
      alice  bob
day             
8/11      0    0
8/25      2    5
9/1       2    0
```

df2

```
      alice  charlie
day                 
9/12      1        1
9/25      2        3
9/1       2        1
```

### Final dataframe df

```
      alice  bob  charlie
day                      
8/11    0.0  0.0      0.0
8/25    2.0  5.0      0.0
9/1     2.0  0.0      1.0
9/12    1.0  0.0      1.0
9/25    2.0  0.0      3.0
```

Comment: Giving me error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'